# OOP Design: Where to put object specific "compare" method?

Tags: oop, class-design, static-methods, ooad, class-method

I have some measurement object instances from a series of test runs stored in a test collection object.  I also have some logic that can compare two test result object instances and tell me if they are "close enough".

Where should this logic be placed?

1. On the object as a method?  Like: `instance.approximately_equal(other)`
2. On the object's class as a class/static method?  `class.approximately_equal(a,b)`
3. On the collection object as a method?  `collection.approximately_equal(a,b)`

What is the correct OO design for this?

(I ask, since although #1 would seem the correct solution, I'd never be asking if some one instance is approximately_equal to a different instance.  Only if "some group of objects" are equal to each other. It got me thinking...)

Thanks

Comment: `approximately_equal` might be a better name than just `compare`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object oriented design books I have read suggest putting cross class functionality into service provider objects.  This will decouple the two objects and reduce complexity, but may be overkill if your project is small.

Comment: Cross class?  All records are same class.

Comment: Something like DistanceConverter/DistanceComparer and WeightConverter/WeightComparer which would contain methods to convert/compare objects of different types.

Comment: Ahh hah... i see.  But in my case, I only have one kind of measurement record object.  Just a whole bunch of instances.  (Frankly, I could have even made them struct type things.. but they are objects.)

Comment: If the 'close enough' question is answering something which is the concern of the class itself then it should be an instance method (e.g. a 'close enough' function on a hitbox object would make sense).  If the comparison is related to the collection (such as a spatial analyzer object that contains a set of generic points) then the comparison should be tied to the collection.  If the comparison is not related to the separated concern of any existing object, then add it to a service provider object created explicitly for that purpose.

Answer (score 1):

I would use option 1 (instance method) since that enables you to refine the comparison logic in derived classes (if needed).

Comment: I would go this route over implementing IComparable.  The problem with IComparable is that you might, in the future, want to also support performing an exact comparison.

Comment: Right, IComparable is certainly not what I want for this.  I do need exact equality testing, too.  For that i'll use IComparable.

Answer (score 0):

I've found #3 is the least obtrusive and leads to less bloated code, because it tends to force you to make those methods as flexible/reusable as possible.  For example, in C++, you'd potentially just use operator overloading to handle it; if you have a utility class (or, if you plan on extending a native data type), the net effect is the same, just with a different presentation.